# What is "epoch_millis" in Elasticsearch? ( date format?)

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading the **Elasticsearch** documents to study about **mappings**. 
I came across **date format** in number 6 in the picture below. According to the official document, `epoch_millis` seems like one of the date formats.

> Did I understand correctly?  Or is it something else? 
>   If it is one of the date formats, can anyone show me an example of that?

[image]
[image]

Comment: @Amadan wow. that is very clear, now. thanks. hey put this as an answer. I am sure other people will appreiciate this as well.

Comment: @Amadan just out of curiousity, what is epoch though? it means anything? you happend to know? :)

Comment: "An [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch), for the purposes of chronology and periodization, is an instant in time chosen as the origin of a particular calendar era. The 'epoch' serves as a reference point from which time is measured."

Comment: @Amadan thanks bro~  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[UNIX epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), in milliseconds; e.g. `1555498747861`.

Answer (score 1):

It is the UNIX epoch time, in milliseconds. It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Thursday, 1 January 1970 till today.

Wikipedia - [UNIX TIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Try this- [EPOCH time converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/clock) to get the epoch time in milliseconds.

Comment: thank you for your answer~ that converter is very useful!

Comment: glad I could help :)